# How do I build a program after cloning a repository from github?

Tags: c++

I want to take this program: https://github.com/baskiton/Img2STL, open it in visual studio and make an executable. I realize I could get it straight from the release, but I want to learn how to edit it and build myself. When I clone it into visual studio, the folders all have blue padlocks next to them and the build function is grayed out.
Thanks!

Comment: This is operating system specific. Consider using [Debian](http://debian.org/)

Comment: Probably there don't seem to be any VS project files in the repo. Your best bet probably is to install cmake on your system and configure a project using the appropriate CMake Generator which should create the solution on your system. It may be possible to use the cmake integration of VS too... https://cmake.org/

Comment: Maybe those might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-170 or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/get-started-linux-cmake?view=msvc-170

Comment: This repository contains CMakeLists.txt file: <https://github.com/baskiton/Img2STL/blob/main%2B%2B/CMakeLists.txt> Cmake supports Windows - see <https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.22.0/cmake-3.22.0-windows-x86_64.msi>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This repo has a `CMakeLists.txt` file in its root, hence this project can be generated and built via [CMake](https://cmake.org/).

Generally you download and install CMake and then you have 2 options:

1. Use GUI.
2. Use your console.
   For Windows you can use powershell:

```
git clone https://github.com/baskiton/Img2STL
cd Img2STL
mdkir build
cd build
cmake ../
```

CMake uses a Generator to configure your projects. It can be defaulted to use your installed Visual Studio.
Or else, you can use Ninja and Visual Studio Code, or Visual Studio with *open folder* to open your project.

This should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I got an error: configuration process, project files may be invalid. Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you ask another question with the error message from a log. Before that, I highly recommend you to read cmake documentation or tutorials and get familliar with the whole concept of how cmake works.